# Как определить содержит ли картинка другую картинку и найти её координаты

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
Есть необходимость определить содержит ли картинка другую картинку, на просторах stackoverflow нашел решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516753/2421703
Только данный метод возвращает лучшее потенциальное совпадение, и получается что даже если картинка не содержит другую картинку он все равно возвращает координаты. Пробовал делать проверку mmr.minVal и mmr.maxVal, но дело в том что для разных картинок и значения будут абсолютно разные.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить задачу.
Благодарю!

Comment: Должен ли быть алгоритм адаптивным? В том плане что искать не точь в точь побайтово, а по "похожести"?

Comment: желательно чтоб было точь в точь

Comment: Что насчёт преобразования обоих картинок в BufferedImage, затем четыре цикла: первые два по координатам точки большей картинки, эту точку мы "совмещаем" с верхним левым углом меньшей картинки, соответственно последние два цикла --- по координатам точки меньшей картинки, проверяют, что пиксель меньшей картинки совпадает с соответствующим пикселем большей.

Comment: как вариант, надо будет попробовать, интересно как будет с производительностью